# In an <article>, can <figure> semantically be put inside <header>?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Let's say I have this,

```
<article>
    <header>
        <h1>Article title</h1>
        <p>Article kicker</p>
        <figure>
            <img class="featured-image" src="http://article.com/featured/image.jpg">
        </figure>
    </header>
    <div class="content">
        <p>Bla bla</p>
        <p>Bla bla</p>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>About author</p>
    </footer>
</article>
```

Is it semantically correct to put the `<figure>` inside `<header>`?

The spec defines `<figure>` as,

> a unit of content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained,
>   that is typically referenced as a single unit from the main flow of
>   the document

If it is put inside `<header>` would that make the `<figure>` belongs to the head of the `<article>` instead of belongs to the `<article>` itself? Tried looking around but I haven't found an answer.

Comment: Minor detail but you're missing a figcaption since your img doesn't have an alt attribute.

Comment: @BoltClock interesting. But that doesn't prevent the figure having both alt in the image and figcaption right?

Comment: Nope, you can still have both - the figcaption provides a description of the image while the alt text is intended as a text replacement for when the image is unavailable. They can either be the same text, or different depending on how you want the alt text to be reflected. See an example here: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#images-that-include-text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure will still be part of the article. It just happens to be in the article header, which is fine if your figure is in fact part of the article header and not the main content of the article.

If you're asking in terms of sectioning, `<header>` and `<footer>` are not sectioning elements, and so the figure will still be part of the article's outline. That is, removing or commenting out the `<header>` and `<footer>` tags:

```
<article>
    <!-- header -->
        <h1>Article title</h1>
        <p>Article kicker</p>
        <figure>
            <img class="featured-image" src="http://article.com/featured/image.jpg">
        </figure>
    <!-- /header -->
    <div class="content">
        <p>Bla bla</p>
        <p>Bla bla</p>
    </div>
    <!-- footer -->
        <p>About author</p>
    <!-- /footer -->
</article>
```

results in the same outline.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! I guess a featured image should be in header than in article content right?

Comment: @deathlock: Sounds about right. I don't know if I've seen a featured image in a figure element though. But it's up to you.

Comment: Why is it so? Is it because featured image shouldn't be able to be taken away?